# Flex iframe shows always top

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

[image]Hi,
I am using iframes in flex 4 but it is shows always top.i am not able to show the tooltip.how to solve this?

please look at the picture.Here i wnat to show the full tooltip of the button but it's hide half becouse of the iframe i need to solve this,how to do this?

Comment: You're going to need to show code and/or a link. Otherwise you're not likely to get any help here.

Comment: plese look at the question.now it's updated  <mx:HBox height="100%" width="100%"> <mx:VBox height="100%" width="5%"> <mx:Spacer height="140"/> <s:Button id="historyBack" toolTip="History Back" rollOver="historyBack_rollOverHandler(event)" label="Back" /> <s:Button id="historyforward" toolTip="History Forward" label="Forware" /> </mx:VBox> <mx:VBox height="100%" width="100%" id="mainvbox"> <flexiframe:IFrame id="testiframe" source="http://search.yahoo.com" height="90%" width="100%"/> </mx:VBox> </mx:HBox>

Comment: hi.. I want to use iFrame in my current Application. I have searched a lot on the net but still not find any useful link. i want to know that how you have use the iFrame component? which are the requirements? what changes needed in .js file etc.. Please Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try decreasin the width of the VBox in which the iframe resides 
So your code should be:

```
<mx:HBox height="100%" width="100%">   
  <mx:VBox height="100%" width="5%">  
    <mx:Spacer height="140"/>
    <s:Button ..label="Back" />
    <s:Button ..label="Forware" />
 </mx:VBox>
 <mx:VBox height="100%" width="90%" id="mainvbox"><!--change this line-->
   <flexiframe:IFrame .. width="100%"/>
 </mx:VBox>
```

EDIT1:
 I got the issue.
This happens , when the iframe tries to be the topmost child in the window.
Can you try the following:
1.Give Iframe and id='iFrame'
2.Add an creationComplete handler for the application

```
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"  creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)"
```

3.In the handler, change the index of this iframe and make it the bottommost compontent.

```
protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    var iFrameIndex:int =this.getChildIndex(this.iFrame);
    this.removeChildAt(iFrameIndex);
    this.addChildAt(this.iFrame,0);
}
```

Try this.The problem should be solved.

just change the width % of the VBox in question and test again.
Please update if that doesnt solve the issue

Comment: hi neeraj,Thanks for your response.my problem is when i load iframe it's shows always top.for example when i click the button that time i displayed one alert message but it displayed back of the iframe.if you are not clear means do this change in back button code. button.<s:Button ..label="Back"  click="Alert.show('Hello World!')"/>

Comment: Have added alternate solutions in Edit1.Please try them out.

Comment: hi neeraj,Thanks for your response.but upto now not able to solve this issue so i moved to As3htmlparser.